# Insert same value in textbox 2 times and checking the values are the same WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm, textbox

i'm trying to implement a feature of a textbox in wpf so that a value need to be inserted 2 times to be accepted as the value, otherwise i need to show an errore like validation error or so.
I need to insert one value in textbox (es: 'asd'), then pressing tab the text disappear and the focus remain in the texbox, and then i need to enter again the same text to be accepted.

right now i'm trying to do it by handling the value in the codebehind in the PreviewKeyInput of the textbox but i'm trying to find a more elegant solution to this.

Comment: I would argue that this is terrible user design, since there will be a hidden state that is not visible to the user. It should be much better to do what everyone does, and have two text-fields that need to match. Or possibly, a confirmation dialog for the user to confirm the values.

Comment: I could agree with you but that are my specifications :D

Comment: I would argue that it is the responsibility of developers to push back against poor specifications. Bugs are *much* cheaper to fix at the specification stage than after release, and I would absolutely classify this as a usability bug. If needed, make the simplest possible implementation and show it to stakeholders, ideally using a very poor keyboard, or on mobile, where mistakes are likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could study this sample to help you.  I am using Caliburn.Micro to implement MVVM

If you are not ok with caliburn, i explain:

1. create a wpf .Net project called **Test**, suppress the files `MainWindow` created.
2. create a window called `MainView` and a view model (class) called `MainViewModel` (its exist a logic with name in caliburn)
3. add a class named `Bootstrapper.cs`

replace **app.xaml** by:

```
<Application x:Class="Test.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <local:Bootstrapper x:Key="Bootstrapper" />
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

---

modify the file **Bootstrapper.cs**:

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using System.Windows;

namespace Test
{
    public class Bootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
    {
        public Bootstrapper()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        protected override async void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            await DisplayRootViewForAsync<MainViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Modify the **MainView.xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
        Title="MainView" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBox x:Name="Login" Width="200" Height="60" Margin="10,10,30,10" Background="AliceBlue" Focusable="True"
                     cal:Message.Attach="[Event LostFocus] = [Action Login_LostFocus($source, $eventargs)];
                                         [Event GotFocus] = [Action Login_GotFocus($source, $eventargs)]"
                     FontSize="12" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Medium"/>
            <Label Name="Validation" Height="60" Width="400" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <Button x:Name="Quit" Content="Quit" Height="60" Width="70" Focusable="True"/>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

Modify the **MainViewModel**:

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Test
{
    public class MainViewModel : Screen
    {
        public string FirstLogin { get; set; }
        private string login;
        public string Login
        {
            get { return login; }
            set
            {
                if (login != value)
                {
                    login = value;
                    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Login);
                }
            }
        }

        private string message;
        public string Message
        {
            get { return message; }
            set
            {
                if (message != value)
                {
                    message = value;
                    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Message); 
                }
            }
        }

        private string validation;
        public string Validation
        {
            get { return validation; }
            set
            {
                if (validation != value)
                {
                    validation = value;
                    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Validation);
                }
            }
        }

        public async void Login_LostFocus(TextBox sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstLogin))
            {
                FirstLogin = Login;
                Login = "";
                //needed before to set focus on TextBox again
                await Task.Delay(100);
                sender.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                if (FirstLogin.Equals(Login))
                    Validation = "Its Ok!!";
                else
                    Validation = "Its not Ok!!";
            }
        }
        public void Login_GotFocus(TextBox sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstLogin) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Login))
            {
                FirstLogin = "";
                Login = "";
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstLogin))
                Validation = "First Try";
            else
                Validation = "Second Try";
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            FirstLogin = "";
            Login = "";
            Validation = "";
        }
    }
}
```

---

I have no set action on Button Quit, it exists just for get Focus when you Tab on TextBox

FYI Caliburn uses the name of Control in view file to link the property with same name in the viewModel..

Comment: Thansk, i'm not using Caliburn.Micro right now but i've managed to find a solution that act like yours by handling the value of the textbox in the codebehind of the view in the keydown event (not really mvvm compliant but..). 
since the textbox.text is binded to a custom class property (es MyClass.Text), i added in the class a second property (TextCheck), and first in the keydown i check if the TextCheck is empty, if so i assign TextCheck = Textbox.Text and then restore the focus in the textbox like you did. 

Thanks.

Comment: happy to help you, dont forget to validate/upvote the answer to close the question